# How to check if a parameter pack contain all elements of other paraments pack

Tags: c++, parameters, c++17

Example:
I have function A with some default arguments, and I want a function that take all the arguments of that function A to check with all arguments I giving. If function A contains all that arguments, then it will call function A with that arguments

Here my sample code:

```
void A(int a = 0, float b = 0.f, double c = 0.0, const char* d = "") {}

template<typename T1, typename...Arg1, typename...Arg2>
void compareArguments(T1(*func)(Arg1...), Arg2...args)
{
    // some code here:
    if (Arg1... contain Arg2...)  // some thing to check
        func(args...);      // call function.
}

int main()
{
   compareArguments(A, 69, 5.5f);
}
```

Any idle?

Comment: The default parameter values are not part of the function signature. Even if you were able to implement the `contain` check, your code would not compile because you don't pass `func` the `double` and `const char*` (i.e. the third and fourth) parameters.

Comment: Function pointers do not contain any info about the default parameters. You cannot make `compareArguments(A, 69, 5.5f)` work with a function pointer for this reason. If you change the function signature to `void A(int, float);`, you could just use `std::is_invocable<T1(*)(Arg1...), Arg2...>` with SFINAE to write 2 overloads that either do nothing or invoke the function (or alternatively use `if constexpr`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As state in comment, when passing `T1(*func)(Arg1...)`, you lose default parameters.

So instead of passing function pointer, you might pass functor:

```
[](auto... args) -> decltype(A(args...)){ return A(args...); }
```

and then [`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) might be used:

```
template<typename F, typename... Ts>
void call(F func, Ts...args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, Ts...>) {
        func(args...);
    }
}
```

with usage

```
call([](auto... args) -> decltype(A(args...)){ return A(args...); }, 69, 5.5f);
```